# MudBlazor MudDataGrid - Calling a method

Tags: datagrid, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I am using the MudBlazor MudDataGrid in a project along with the MudDataGridPager.  I am displaying a row count above the grid which is justa count of my List. But I would like to display the row count as it changes when using filters.
I am using the quick filter option for searching and it works perfectly.  The pager shows the result count with the grid etc. as it changes.  I would like to update my display with that value.  In the MudBlazor API documentation there is a method called GetFilteredItemsCount() which is exactly what I need.  It can be viewed here:
[MudDataGrid - API](https://mudblazor.com/api/datagrid#methods)

My question is, how do I call this method?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please check this very simple example: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QkccbkverDkJnZfX Best

Comment: WOW, thank you so much!.  That very simple example is just what I needed.  That try mudblazor sandbox is excellent and helped me very much.  I have never used the @ref before.  I have seen in in Angular apps, but didn't know it exists in Blazor.  SUPER SUPER helpful example with demo!!!!